# JPA query being cached wrong

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a REST API in spring boot

My API calls two spring data repos sequentially. There are 4 sessions in the table out of which 1 has sessionKey=1L

1. `sessionRepository.findBySessionKey(1L)`
2. `sessionRepository.findAll()`

The second returns only 1 result however 4 are expected.
When i move these sequential calls out of a REST API and call as a method from integration test it returns 4 results. Also If i call the API from integration test the return is 1 (So the REST API config is ok)

It seems the values are being stored in the persistence context and stale data is being showed next time. Can someone explain better ?

Comment: Could you provide some configuration files ?

Comment: Please, do not ask your questions again. If you consider it, edit them, but asking again makes no sense. Edit your other question and provide more info about configuration, it's impossible to guess anything else as you've stated it.